# Retrieve multiple filenames via Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple app with Tkinter that can select multiple files and get their full path + filenames respectively.
Currently, the app can select multiple files but seems fail to get the full path, any pointer on this would be great.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import os  
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x100') 


def browse():
    filename = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('files', '*.csv')], multiple=True)
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)

browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browse)
browsebutton.pack()

pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()        
        
mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use `askopenfilenames()` if you want filenames only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()` this will return a tuple containing the file paths of the files chosen. To obtain the file names, you can make use of the `os.path.basename(file/path)` this will return the corresponding file name (along with the extension). You can refer to the modified code below:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os  
root = Tk() 

def browse():
    files = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('files', '*.csv')], multiple=True)
    file_paths=''
    file_names=''
    for file in files:
        file_paths+=file+'\n'
        file_names+=os.path.basename(file)+'\n'
    pathlabel.config(text=file_paths)
    namelabel.config(text=file_names)

browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browse)
browsebutton.pack()

path_head=Label(root,text='File Paths').pack()
pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()       
name_head=Label(root,text='File Names').pack()
namelabel=Label(root)
namelabel.pack() 
        
mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, may i know if i just want to select the 2nd file path, can i use index to access it?

Comment: As the variable `files` holds a tuple containing all the file paths, you can use index to access its elements

Comment: i have add  pathlabe2 =files[1] after the the ....config. And also add following to show the output : name_head=Label(root,text='File Paths2').pack()
pathlabel2 = Label(root)
pathlabel2.pack()       Still cannot retrieve the 2nf file path, any idea?

Comment: According to this `pathlabe2` is a `Label` right, then how are you performing `pathlabe2 =files[1]`? This will just reassign the variable, if you want the new label to display the text the use `.config()` on it

Comment: I have implemented it in code here https://pastebin.com/EY58ZUtf let me know if that satisfies your requirement